# Logstash - Join two Dicts

Tags: logstash

i wrote a small working example to explain my question:

```
input {
  stdin {
      codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        rename => { "[DictA]" => "[ZielDict]" } 
        rename => { "[DictB]" => "[ZielDict]" } 
    }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```

Input

```
{
"DictA": {
    "valueA": 123
},
"DictB": {
    "valueB": 456
}
}
```

Output

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "78f85c66a671",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-11-15T12:11:01.193Z,
      "ZielDict" => {
        "valueB" => 456
    }
}
```

Wanted Output (i dont want to override DictA!)

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "78f85c66a671",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-11-15T12:11:01.193Z,
      "ZielDict" => {
        "valueA" => 123
        "valueB" => 456
    }
}
```

So as you can see i want to append to the ZielDict instead of overriding it with DictB. How can i handle this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [mutate.merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-merge) option:

```
input {
  stdin {
      codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        merge => { "DictA" => "DictB" } 
    }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```

With this configuration, you get:

```
{
    "host" => "frsred-0077",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-11-15T13:54:19.923Z,
    "DictA" => {
        "valueB" => 456,
        "valueA" => 123
    },
    "DictB" => {
        "valueB" => 456
    },
    "@version" => "1"
}
```

You'll have to remove the `DictB` field and rename the `DictA` to get your wanted output.